# how to write a static class that has an id with a string in it

Tags: java

I want to write a static class customer ID that begins with C1000, and for each new customer object created it will add +1, C1001, C1002, C1003, and so on.  How is it done if there is a string?

```
public class Customer
{
    private static int customerID = 1000;

    public Customer()
    {
        customerID++;
    }

    public static int getcutomerID()
    {
        return customerID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Customer {
    private static int NextCustomerId = 1000;
    private final int myCustomerId;

    public Customer() {
        myCustomerId = NextCustomerId++;
        ...
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return "C" + myCustomerId;
    }
}
```

Note that this probably isn't threadsafe. If you need it to be, look at [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()) and use one of those for `NextCustomerId`.

Comment: nah ... he's better off not using a static variable at all ... he should separate the concern of issuing new customer ids out from the Customer class - maybe create an IdGenerator (or CustomerDatabase as I've included in my modified response). Makes it easy to test if there is no static state. How does serialization work if you have static state? A number of issues just crop up with ... static state ...

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Customer {
    private static int customerID = 1000;

    // wth would you do this?! static state is evil!
    public Customer() { customerID++; }

    public String getCurrentCustomerID() { return "C" + customerID; }
}
```

Static state is very bad for testing. It amounts to global variables. Perhaps a better design is:

```
public class Customer {
    private final int id;
    public Customer(final int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
}

public class CustomerDatabase {
    private int nextId;

    public CustomerDatabase() { this(0); }
    public CustomerDatabase(int nextId) { this.nextId = nextId; }

    public synchronized int nextId() { return nextId++; }

    // define useful operations for a CustomerDatabase
}

// maybe you could use the database and customer classes as follows
public class CustomerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // first argument is highest customer id
        CustomerDatabase db = new CustomerDatabase(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        Customer c = new Customer(db.nextId());
        db.add(c);

        System.out.println(db.getCustomers());

        db.save("customers.txt");

        Customer x = db.findById(13);
        if(x.isBroke()) db.delete(x);

        System.out.println("K thx, bai");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an overkill, is there no better method to solving his problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Use an `int` with [`String.format()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).